# How to convert this data structure of JSON to python dict?

Tags: python, json

I have parsed some JSON data to dict in python3, using json module.

In the result dict, some data remains in the form of string, similar to
's:4:"name";s:5:"value";s:5:"array";a:4:{etc...}'

What is the proper name of this, and how can I further convert to a dict, like 
{"name":"value", "array": [etc...]}

Comment: Please provide the input data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest ways is to use `json`:

```
import json


str_dict = "{'one': 'three', 'two': 'four'}"
new_dict = json.loads(str_dict)
```

Edit: You can also use `ast`:

```
import ast


srt_dict = "{'five': 'seven', 'six': 'eight'}"
new_dict = ast.literal_eval(str_dict)
```

Edit: You can also use `eval()`, however the docs recommend using literal_eval:

```
str_dict = "{'nine': 'ten', 'eleven': 'twelve'}"
new_dict = eval(str_dict)
```

There are more ways out there on the internet, however these are what I consider to be the simplest of them.

Comment: The answers here are wrong so far. Everyone misanderstood my question, however the data format I have enclosed is clearly not json or python syntax either. I have recieved the right answer on a different forum. The data is php, and I managed to convert it with the phpserialize module.